# Como seria la jerarquía de los if en este código?

Tags: python

```
print("Bienvenido a BitBank, por favor digite los siguientes datos para saber su nivel de prioridad")

for i in range(3):
    nombre = input("Digite su nombre: ")
    edad = int(input("Digite su edad: "))
    tiempo = int(input("Digite la duracion estimada de su diligencia (en minutos): "))
    prioridad = edad/tiempo

    print(f"NOMBRE: {nombre}")
    print(f"Edad/Tiempo: {round (prioridad, 2)}")
    if prioridad < 2:
        print("Prioridad: BAJA")
    if prioridad >= 2 , prioridad < 5:
        print("Prioridad: NORMAL")
    if prioridad >= 5:
        print("Prioridad: ALTA")
```

Comment: Que tratas de hacer en el segundo `if`? Por que pones una coma?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes reducir el código entiendo bien como quedan las condiciones:

```
if prioridad < 2:
    print("Prioridad: BAJA")
elif prioridad < 5:
    print("Prioridad: NORMAL")
else:
    print("Prioridad: ALTA")
```

Si la primera condición no se cumple, entonces `prioridad` tiene que ser >= 2, por lo que sólo me resta comparar < 5 para chequear que sea prioridad NORMAL (2 <= prioridad < 5).

Si ninguna de las condiciones se cumple, entonces no puede ser < 2 ni < 5. Basta con un `else`; ya se que el valor está en el rango.